# How to prevent concurrency issue with database update?

Tags: database, concurrency

I have the following sequence which may be executed by more than one instance of my program at any time:

> **Step 1:** Check to see whether bill is unpaid
>
> **Step 2:** If bill is unpaid, then mark bill as paid

I am worried that Instance 1 and Instance 2 of my program will both do Step 1 at almost exactly the same time and therefore proceed to both do Step 2.  How can I prevent this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Using a (serializable) `TRANSACTION`.  More details depend on your database platform

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction for details

Comment: Please elaborate. How will a transaction help?  If both instances of my program execute the steps in a transaction, how does that help?

Comment: They would be in different transactions, and one would fail, which you could trap, and take appropriate action

Comment: That depends on the exact structure of your code and operations - it may just wait until the first transaction was complete and then proceed, by which point the atomic nature of the first transaction would be complete, and so produce a different result. To be more precise, more detail is needed.

Comment: My program runs concurrently on two or more machines. Each instance may run the above sequence at any time.

Comment: What database are you using? What is this program written in? How is one connecting to the other? Where is this database code generated? etc

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be concrete about this without seeing code, but the obvious way to do this is to combine steps 1 and 2.

So, instead of:

```
$invoice_status = call_database(
select INVOICE_STATUS
from   INVOICES
where  INVOICE_ID = $invoice_id)

if ($invoice_status = UNPAID){
   call_database (
      UPDATE INVOICES 
      SET INVOICE_STATUS = PAID 
      WHERE INVOICE_ID = $invoice_id)
}
```

You would do something like

```
call_database(
   update invoices
   set    invoice_status = PAID
   where  invoice_id = $invoice_id
   and    invoice_status = UNPAID)
```

Comment: With your second code segment, how would you report back to the user that the update wasn't made because the invoice was already paid? With your code the query would just run successfully.