# Transaction isolation in JET?

Tags: database, ms-access, oledb, jet, isolation-level

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724261%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) describes the JET transaction isolation for its OLEDB provider as follows:

> Jet supports five levels of nesting in transactions. The only
>   supported mode for transactions is Read Committed. Setting lesser
>   levels of transactional separation implies Read Committed. Setting
>   higher levels will cause StartTransaction to fail.
>
> Jet supports only single-phase commit.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259216%28SQL.80%29.aspx) describes `Read Committed` as follows:

> Specifies that shared locks are held while the data is being read to
>   avoid dirty reads, but the data can be changed before the end of the
>   transaction, resulting in nonrepeatable reads or phantom data. This
>   option is the SQL Server default.

---

My questions are:

1. What is single-phase commit?  What consequence does this have for transactions and isolation?
2. Would the Read Committed isolation level as described above be suitable for my requirements [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002411/how-to-prevent-concurrency-issue-with-database-update)?
3. What is the best way to achieve a Serializable transaction isolation using Jet?

Answer (score 1):

By question number:

1. Single-phase commit is used where all of your data is in one database -- the activity of the transaction is committed atomically and you're done.  If you have a logical transaction which needs to be spread across multiple storage engines (like a relational database for metadata and some sort of document store for a big blob) you can use a *transaction manager* to coordinate the activities so that the work is persisted in both or neither, if both products support *two phase commit*.  They are just telling you that they *don't* support two-phase commit, so the product is not suitable for distributed transactions.
2. Yes, if you check the condition in the `UPDATE` statement itself; otherwise you might have problems.
3. They seem to be suggesting that you can't.

As an aside, I worked for decades as a consultant in quite a variety of environments.  More than once I was engaged to migrate people *off* of Jet because of performance problems.  In one case a simple "star" type query was running for two minutes because it was joining on the client rather than letting the database do it.  As a direct query against the database it was sub-second.  In another case there was a report which took 72 hours to run through Jet, which took 2 minutes when run directly against the database.  If it generally works OK for you, you might be able to deal with such situations by using stored procedures where Jet is causing performance pain.

Comment: Comparing speed of JET vs SQL server,  you find as a general rule that a significant number of JET operations are going to be MUCH faster than using SQL server. SQL server has several layers of software, a log file, and a transaction layer between your software and the data. In the case of JET, you not are using a server, you not using or connecting to a service, and in most cases you not connecting to the data through some socket (network) connection. The result is you are directly using the disk drive as a file and the result is MUCH higher performance then SQL server by a significant amount